# Possibility to record playback of browser audio element using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, mediarecorder-api

I am currently working on a simple audio project which uses HTML / JS audio elements to play audio using buttons.

Is it somehow possible to record that audio being played instead of recording the microphone (by using the MediaRecorder API)?

Comment: This possible with the Web Audio API, not Audio elements. First you'd [convert the audio to an AudioBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BaseAudioContext/decodeAudioData) via an Audio Context, then [set that buffer on a BufferSource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBufferSourceNode), which [connects to a MediaStreamDestination](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/createMediaStreamDestination), which you can then finally pass to MediaRecorder. You then control the audio via the BufferSource, not an HTML/JS element.

Comment: Alright, I will look into that, thank you. Is it also possible to use multiple streams and record them together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After following the steps provided by [lawrence-witt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12799351/lawrence-witt), I figured it out. Here an example for everyone trying to achieve the same:

```
const audioContext = new AudioContext();
const destination = audioContext.createMediaStreamDestination();
const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(destination.stream);

// array of 'new Audio()' elements
audioArray.forEach(audio => {
    let stream = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(audio.captureStream());
    stream.connect(destination);
})

mediaRecorder.start();
```